Why can’t a superclass call a subclass’s methods?
I’m a computer science teacher at a high school, and I’m teaching polymorphism in Java. My students asked me this question, and I didn’t have a good answer.
Let’s say I have an Employee class. Also, I have a Lawyer class which is a subclass of Employee. Now let’s say the method sue() is defined in the Lawyer class, but not in the Employee class. Given all of this, the following code will cause an error:
Employee ed = new Lawyer();
ed.sue();

The question is, why is the Java language built this way, that this causes an error? All Lawyers can sue, and ed is a reference pointing at a Lawyer object, so shouldn’t ed be able to sue?
This is totally opposed to what one would expect from logical reasoning in the real world, in a casual conversation, outside the context of computer programming. Let’s say I’m in an office building, talking to a CEO, and he says:
“This is Ed, one of my employees, and he’s a lawyer. Not every employee in my company can sue people, but the lawyers can sue people.”
If I heard the CEO say this, I would come to the conclusion that Ed can sue people.
Am I missing something in this analogy? Basically I’m saying that this code:
Employee ed = new Lawyer();

is analogous to the following statement:
“This is Ed, one of my employees, and he’s a lawyer.”
I’m also saying that when we define the sue() method in the Lawyer class, but not in the Employee class, that’s analogous to saying “not every employee can sue, but lawyers can sue.”
By the way, I know that there are ways to get around this limitation in Java. For example, I could cast Ed as a lawyer.
Employee ed = new Lawyer();
((Lawyer)ed).sue();

And this would not cause an error.
Or, I could simply use a Lawyer reference in the first place:
Lawyer ed = new Lawyer();
ed.sue();

This would not cause an error.
Or, I could define the sue() method in the Employee class, such that the Lawyer’s version of sue() is overriding the version from Employee, and then the original two lines of code would run just fine without errors.
But why do we need to use these workarounds at all? Why can’t a superclass reference, pointing to a subclass object, call the subclass’s methods? Why is Java built this way?

Employee ed = new Lawyer(); is analogous to the following statement: “This is Ed, one of my employees, and he’s a lawyer.” No, it's just "this is one of my employees". He happens to be a lawyer, but could be any other employee.

You've got a compiler error; the compiler considers only what the variable is declared as. The class Employee doesn't have a sue() method. As far as this question is concerned, the code might as well be Object obj = new Lawyer();.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system

I will add that your object model is wrong. In the real world we don't model real things like that, only computing concepts. In the real world 'lawyer' would be a role of Employee, not a derived class. Consider the case where an Employee becomes a Manager, and perhaps later ceases to be a Manager again. You don't want to tie your object model in fits modelling this sort of thing.

This is not a 'limitation in Java'. Static typing allows us to make very useful statements about what types a reference can refer to. Employee ed tells you that you cannot assume that ed refers to a Lawyer and that you may assign a reference to a Doctor to ed. Being able to express these constraints, and have the compiler check them, makes your code easier to understand, and removes sources of bugs.
Looking at your work arounds:
Employee ed = new Lawyer();
((Lawyer)ed).sue();

Will throw a ClassCastException if ed doesn't refer to a Lawyer.
If you add a sue() method to Employee, how will you implement it for subclasses other than Lawyer?
The only correct solution is:
Lawyer ed = new Lawyer();
ed.sue();

Where you make explicit the constraint that ed must refer to a Lawyer instance.

The thing about variables is that their contents are variable ...
So let's slightly modify your example:
Lawyer ed = new Lawyer();
Employee onDuty = ed; // ed is currently on duty

// sometime later
onDuty.sue(); // error: the employee on duty may not be a lawyer

Why this error? Because the employee on duty may have changed in the meantime. Just because the first employee on duty happened to be a Lawyer doesn't mean that they all are.
Put differently, if they are all known to be lawyers, we should really talk about the "Lawyer on duty" rather than the "Employee on duty", so that we get a nice error when somebody tries to assign a Secretary to the duty roster.

An Employee can have many subclasses, another of which could be Janitor for instance.  When you do
Employee ed = new Lawyer();

You are creating a Lawyer but, with static typing, ed knows only that it refers to an Employee, which could just as easily be a Janitor.
If you know that ed is a Lawyer, you can "downcast" to Lawyer to access the sue() method:
if (ed instanceof Lawyer) ((Lawyer) ed).sue();  // Old style cast

or 

if (ed instanceof Lawyer edlaw) edlaw.sue(); // Modern pattern matching

That's just how static typing in Java works.  An object reference knows only about its declared class and that class' methods.  You can cast to a subclass if you are sure of the dynamic type.
